# Confused with 3 models and different associations between them

Tags: sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, associations

I have 3 main models:

Chefs, Cuisines and Ingredients.

Chefs and Cuisines are a many to many relation.
I have a Chefs_Cuisines table to maintain this many to many.

The ingredients model is a complete list of ingredients.

One chef can select many cuisines.

So let’s say chef Mario (id=1) selected Italian(id=1) and Greek(id=2) for the cuisines he is familiar with.

And chef Satoro(id=2) selected Italian(id=1) and Japanese(id=3)

So the Chefs_Cuisines Table will look like this.

```
chef_id | cuisine_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 1
2       | 3
```

Now for each cuisine each chef has they must form a list of ingredients.

So Mario(id=1) for his Italian(id=1) dishes selected Tomato(id=1), Cheese(id=2), Flour(id=3)
And for the greek dish(id=2) Mario selected Tomato(id=1) Cucumber(id=4) and eggplants(id=5)
Satoro chose Salmon(id=6) and Rice(id=7) for his Japanese(id=3) course.

So I need another table to keep track of this. Something like Chefs_Cuisines_Ingredients

```
chef_id | cuisine_id | ingredient_id
1       | 1          | 1
1       | 1          | 2
1       | 1          | 3
1       | 2          | 1
1       | 2          | 4
1       | 2          | 5
2       | 3          | 6
2       | 3          | 7
```

Note that at the moment Satoro(2) chose not to select any ingredients to his Italian(1) menu.

My models look like this.

## Chefs

```
Class Chef
has_many: chefs_cuisines
has_many: cuisines, through => :chefs_cuisines
# This enables me to assign any cuisine for each chef, regardless of ingredients that will be selected later.

has_many: chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: cuisines,    through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: ingredients, through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
```

## Cuisines

```
Class Cuisine
has_many: chefs_cuisines
has_many: chefs, through => :chefs_cuisines

has_many: chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: chefs,       through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: ingredients, through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
```

## Ingredients

```
Class Ingredient
has_many: chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: chefs,       through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
has_many: cuisines,    through => :chefs_cuisines_ingredients
```

## Chefs_Cuisines

```
Class Chefs_cuisine
belongs_to: chef
belongs_to: cuisine
```

## Chefs_Cuisines_Ingredients

```
Class Chefs_cuisines_ingredient
belongs_to: chef
belongs_to: cuisine
belongs_to: ingredient
```

So first I assigned the chefs to the cuisines.
Chef Mario has 2 cuisines, Italian and Greek.
Then I have a screen for Mario where I choose one of the cuisine and can select the ingredients for that.
But when I save it for the Italian cuisine with italian ingredients, the greek gets deleted from Class Chefs_cuisines.

This is not what I want, the greek is still part of his skill.
In this case I want to add the relation to the chefs_cuisines_ingredients, it has nothing to do with the chefs_cuisines model.

I am a bit lost on how to achieve this and how to associate these models together, any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Since its a `has_many :through` relation,you can just add `belongs_to :ingredient` in `Chefs_cuisine` model itself,no need of  `Chefs_cuisines_ingredient` model

Comment: Thanks, and where do I store the ingredient_id?

Comment: In the `chefs_cuisines` table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt that to do what I wanted you need to rename the Models, so RoR does not get confused as me and change relations you don't want it to change.

The solution for the Chefs_Cuisine link table is:

## Chefs_Cuisines

```
class Chefs_Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :nationality, class_name: "Cuisine", foreign_key: "cuisine_id"
    belongs_to :cook,        class_name: "Chef",    foreign_key: "chef_id"
end
```

## Chefs

```
class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chefs_cuisines
  has_many :nationalities, class_name: "Cuisine", foreign_key: "cuisine_id", :through => :chefs_cuisines 
end
```

## Cuisines

```
class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :chefs_cuisines
  has_many :cooks, class_name: "Chef", foreign_key: "chef_id", :through => :chefs_cuisines 
end
```

With that we have "different" models that use the same classes and database table, but are totally independent. So making changes in the Chefs_Cuisine_Ingredients will not change the relation in Chefs_Cuisines.

So when you instance:

```
@chef = Chef.first
```

You will refer to the Cuisines using:

```
@chef.nationalities
```

And to the Chefs_Cuisines_Ingredient using:

```
@chef.cuisines
```

Neat!

And to update Chefs_Cuisines_Ingredients, given that it can't be done with ActiveRecord, I used something like this:

```
cuisine_ids    = chefs_params.delete(:cuisine_id)
ingredient_ids = chefs_params.delete(:ingredient_id)
chef.chefs_cuisines_ingredients.where("cuisine_id=#{cuisine_ids}").destroy_all
ingredient_ids.each do |ingredient_id|
    cuisine_ids.each do |cuisine_id|
      chef.userspostcodes.create(ingredient_id: ingredient_id, cuisine_id: cuisine_id, chef_id: chef.id)
    end
end
```